# How do you use WHERE NOT EXISTS with WITH?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got two sets with the same columns and I'm trying to get a list of items in the first set that do not exist in the second. The second list is built from a recursive select that uses `WITH` and I can't figure out how to use that with `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Fruit]
        ,[Color]
    FROM [dbo].[CostCentreMapping]
    WHERE [Color] IS NOT NULL
        AND [Color] <> ''
        AND LEFT([Fruit], 1) = 'C'
    ) AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        --Incorrect syntax error occurs here
        WITH tmp(Fruit, DataItem, ManyColors) AS (
                SELECT Fruit
                    ,CAST(LEFT(ManyColors, CHARINDEX(',', ManyColors + ',') - 1) AS VARCHAR(200))
                    ,CAST(STUFF(ManyColors, 1, CHARINDEX(',', ManyColors + ','), '') AS VARCHAR(200))
                FROM ExecutiveSummaryDisplay

                UNION ALL

                SELECT Fruit
                    ,CAST(LEFT(ManyColors, CHARINDEX(',', ManyColors + ',') - 1) AS VARCHAR(200))
                    ,CAST(STUFF(ManyColors, 1, CHARINDEX(',', ManyColors + ','), '') AS VARCHAR(200))
                FROM tmp
                WHERE ManyColors > ''
                )
        SELECT DISTINCT Fruit AS [Fruit]
            ,DataItem AS [Color]
        FROM tmp
        WHERE Fruit IS NOT NULL
            AND Fruit <> ''
            AND DataItem IS NOT NULL
            AND DataItem <> ''
        )
```

Comment: CTE's go first in your code. If you want to reference the CTE within itself (with cte as (select from cte), it will get a little more confusing since it is now recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a temporary table:

```
WITH tmp(Fruit, DataItem, ManyColors) AS
    (
        SELECT
            Fruit,
            CAST(LEFT(ManyColors, CHARINDEX(',', ManyColors + ',') - 1) as varchar(200)),
            CAST(STUFF(ManyColors, 1, CHARINDEX(',', ManyColors + ','), '') as varchar(200))
        FROM ExecutiveSummaryDisplay
        UNION all

        SELECT
            Fruit,
            CAST(LEFT(ManyColors, CHARINDEX(',', ManyColors + ',') - 1) as varchar(200)),
            CAST(STUFF(ManyColors, 1, CHARINDEX(',', ManyColors + ','), '') as varchar(200))
        FROM tmp
        WHERE
            ManyColors > ''
    )

    SELECT DISTINCT INTO #TEMPTABLE
        Fruit AS [Fruit],
        DataItem AS [Color]
    FROM tmp
    WHERE Fruit IS NOT NULL AND Fruit <> '' AND DataItem IS NOT NULL AND DataItem <> '')


    SELECT DISTINCT [Fruit]
          ,[Color]
      FROM [dbo].[CostCentreMapping]
      WHERE [Color] IS NOT NULL AND [Color] <> '' AND LEFT([Fruit], 1) = 'C'
            AND NOT EXISTS(
                select * from #TEMPTABLE T WHERE 
                T.Color=CostCentreMapping.Color AND 
                T.Fruit=CostCentreMapping.Fruit)
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff. . . It has `#TEMPTABLE`.

Comment: `EXISTS` never seems to work for me. I did end up using #TEMPTABLE though, just did a left join and null check against it instead of using `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do :

```
with tmp (Fruit, DataItem, ManyColors) as
(
  select . . . 
  union 
  select . . .
)

SELECT DISTINCT [Fruit], [Color]
FROM [dbo].[CostCentreMapping] cm
WHERE [Color] IS NOT NULL AND [Color] <> '' AND LEFT([Fruit], 1) = 'C') AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tmp where . . .);
```

Comment: If I run the select against `tmp` and another against `cm` I can see that I'm getting two valid sets with common records. But as soon as `NOT EXISTS` is there I get nothing back.

Comment: @Legion. . . I can't follow your current `where` clause so, i just left it by `. . . ` . So, you just need to define correct where clause to reference from outer object `cm` should do what you want.

Comment: I've never been able to get `EXISTS` to work and that trend continues today. Ended up just using a left join with a null check against a temp table.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a temporary table #TEMPTABLE, here is another solution:

```
WITH tmp(Fruit, DataItem, ManyColors) AS
    (
        SELECT
            Fruit,
            CAST(LEFT(ManyColors, CHARINDEX(',', ManyColors + ',') - 1) as varchar(200)),
            CAST(STUFF(ManyColors, 1, CHARINDEX(',', ManyColors + ','), '') as varchar(200))
        FROM ExecutiveSummaryDisplay
        UNION all

        SELECT
            Fruit,
            CAST(LEFT(ManyColors, CHARINDEX(',', ManyColors + ',') - 1) as varchar(200)),
            CAST(STUFF(ManyColors, 1, CHARINDEX(',', ManyColors + ','), '') as varchar(200))
        FROM tmp
        WHERE
            ManyColors > ''
    )


     SELECT DISTINCT [Fruit], [Color]
      FROM [dbo].[CostCentreMapping]
      WHERE [Color] IS NOT NULL AND [Color] <> '' AND LEFT([Fruit], 1) = 'C'
      AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT Fruit AS [Fruit], DataItem AS [Color] FROM tmp T
                     WHERE Fruit IS NOT NULL AND Fruit <> '' AND DataItem IS NOT NULL AND DataItem <> ''
                     and T.Color=CostCentreMapping.Color AND T.Fruit=CostCentreMapping.Fruit
                     )
```